# how to make a structure point to itself without valgrind complaining

Tags: c, pointers, structure, valgrind, c99

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>
#include<string.h>
#include<assert.h>

struct Person{
    char *name;
    char sex;
    int age;
    struct Person *ancestor;       
    int n;
};

void p_person(struct Person *this);

struct Person *stack_init()
{
    struct Person *this=malloc(sizeof(struct Person));
    assert(this!=NULL);

    this->name=strdup("NULL");
    this->sex='0';
    this->age=-1;
    this->ancestor=NULL;
    this->n=1;

    return this;
}

struct Person *pushPerson(struct Person *this, char *name, char sex, int age)
{
    assert(this!=NULL);
    int n=this->n+1;
    this=realloc(this,sizeof(struct Person)*n);

    this[n-1].name=strdup(name);
    this[n-1].sex=sex;
    this[n-1].age=age;
    this[n-1].ancestor=&this[n-2];

    printf("pushing new person onto stack\n");
    printf("stack increasing to %d\n",this->n);
    p_person(&this[n-1]);

    this->n=this->n+1;
    /*p_person(this[n-1].ancestor); //it works*/
    printf("----------------\n\n");

    return this;
}

struct Person *popPerson(struct Person *this)
{
    assert(this!=NULL);
    printf("Person being popped:\n");
    p_person(&this[this->n-1]);
    printf("resizing stack to %d\n", this->n-2);
    printf("----------------\n\n");
    free(this[this->n-1].name);
    int n=this->n-1;
    this=realloc(this,sizeof(struct Person)*n);

    this->n=this->n-1;

    return this;
}

void p_person(struct Person *this)
{
    printf("Name: %s\n",this->name);
    printf("Sex: %c\n",this->sex);
    printf("Age: %d\n",this->age);
}

void p_person_stack(struct Person *this)
{
    printf("printing stack...........\n");
    struct Person *current;
    int i;
    for(i=1;i<this->n;i++)
    {
        current=&this[i];
        p_person(current);
        printf("---------\n");
    }
    printf("stack printed~~~~~~~~~~\n\n");
}

void d_person_stack(struct Person *this)
{
    int i;
    for(i=0;i<this->n;i++)
        free(this[i].name);
    free(this);
}

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    struct Person *people=stack_init();

    people=pushPerson(people,"Mojo jojo", 'M', 33);
    people=pushPerson(people,"Ali Zaheeruddin", 'M', 24);
    people=pushPerson(people,"Mahdi Moosa", 'M', 24);
    people=pushPerson(people,"Solid Snake", 'M', 51);  

    d_person_stack(people);

    return 0;
}
```

p_person(&people[n]) works fine without valgrind complaining where n is within the range of the stack

p_person(people[n].ancestor) makes valgrind complain about invalid read of size x depending what it is reading in the structure Person for example char sex will be x=1
the exception here is when n is the end of the stack (4 in this case) valgrind will not complain, for all cases of n the result will be printed fine.

this is an example of what valgrind will say if I do p_person(people[n].ancestor) where n
is less than the end of stack

Invalid read of size 8
Name: Ali Zaheeruddin
Invalid read of size 1
Sex: M
Invalid read of size 4
Age:24

Comment: Using subtractions on (array-)indicies is error prone, try to avoid it.

Comment: what should i use instead?

Comment: OT: If possible use a modified or different algorithm. If changing `int n=this->n+1;` to be `int n=this->n;` you could avoid all occurrences of `n-1` for example. This is not about solving your specific issue, but about how to right more stable/saver code by concept/approach.

Comment: thanks for this safe practice i've implemented it, now i have to fix the main problem

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
this[n-1].ancestor=&this[n-2];
```

When you have 0 or 1 existing elements in the array the n-2 goes below the start of the array, causing an invalid read of the memory at that address (8 bytes).

Comment: that's fine, when it goes down to 1 existing element, that's the Person filled with gibberish values and the ancestor of that is NULL, the second element is a real person pointing to the giberish person. The design is bad, i'm going to fix it, however you didn't answer the question as to why valgrind is complaining when there are 2 or more elements

Comment: Valgrind seems to be complaining when "Ali Zaherrunddin" is being processed. He is the 2nd name to be added, so there is only 1 element at that time. The call to /*p_person(this[n-1].ancestor); //it works*/ is where valgrind detects the invalid read.

Comment: ok i fixed it by using a forloop which reassigns all previous ancestors in the push and pop functions, i think realloc function was messing something up